# If azure sql database is crossing the 1tb limit, how to add a database to it?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have an azure sql database. The max size of an azure sql db is 1TB. If my db is going to cross the limit, what can I do to increase the size. Can I add another database to it. How can I do that? What would be a strategy for implementing multiple databases?

Comment: Something else to consider is compression.  Are your tables using clustered columnstore index?  They can give great compression and performance depending on the data and query types.  Clustered columnstore would be a good combination with aggregate queries (`GROUP BY`, `COUNT`, `SUM` etc) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One answer is to look at the public preview for 4 TB - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers#choosing-a-service-tier

**some more details :**

> Customers using P11 and P15 performance levels can use up to 4 TB of included storage at no additional charge. This 4 TB option is currently in public preview in the following regions: US East2, West US, West Europe, South East Asia, Japan East, Australia East, Canada Central, and Canada East.

These are some limitations :

- When creating or updating a P11 or P15 database, you can only chose between 1 TB and 4 TB maxsize. Intermediate storage sizes are not currently supported.
  The 4 TB database maxsize cannot be changed to 1 TB even if the actual storage used is below 1 TB. Thus, you cannot downgrade a P11-4TB/P15-4TB to a P11-1TB/P15-1TB or a lower performance tier (e.g., to P1-P6) until we are providing additional storage options for the rest of the performance tiers. This restriction also applies to the restore and copy scenarios including point-in-time, geo-restore, long-term-backup-retention, and database copy. Once a database is configured with the 4 TB option, all restore operations of this database must be into a P11/P15 with 4 TB maxsize.

**For Active Geo-Replication scenarios:**
1.)    Setting up a geo-replication relationship: If the primary database is P11 or P15, the secondary(ies) must also be P11 or P15; lower performance tiers will be rejected as secondaries since they are not capable of supporting 4 TB.

2.)  Upgrading the primary database in a geo-replication relationship: Changing the maxsize to 4 TB on a primary database will trigger the same change on the secondary database. Both upgrades must be successful for the change on the primary to take effect. Region limitations for the 4TB option apply (see above). If the secondary is in a region that does not support 4 TB, the primary will not be upgraded.

3.) Using the Import/Export service for loading P11-4TB/P15-4TB databases is not supported. Use SqlPackage.exe to import and export data.